# Customer Login Page randomly stopped working

Tags: customer

For some reason the customer login page on my site has just totally stopped working and just refreshes.

https://www.coffeeseller.com/customer/account/login/

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is no problem in you login page check your `username` and `password`. i test it with these credential `test@test.com` and pwd `test123`

Answer (score -1):

Open the Login Form view file and add between the `<form>` tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Refresh the cache & check.